# Invalid CSS after "...ound-image:url:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " ../images/pict..."

Tags: css

I get this error when trying to load my CSS. I've read that whitespaces are a problem in CSS. I suspect maybe it's the syntax of how I specify the URL where the pictures live. Here is the code:

```
.post {
  width: 368px;
  height: 376px;
  background-image: url: "../images/pictures of liana/" The Cutest Face Ever.jpg);
  position: absolute;
}
.post img {
  width: 335px;
  height: 275px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 15px;
}
.post p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2E2E2E;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: The [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) would have shown you exactly where the error lies.

Comment: Whitespaces are not really a problem in CSS. Not sure where you read that. Other than in obvious places. Where are you getting that error? It doesn't look like a `console` message, so I'm assuming some validator.

Comment: You'll need to escape the whitescape in the `url(...)` of `background-image` and your syntax is invalid. Replace it with :- `background-image: url(../images/pictures%20of%20liana/The%20Cutest%20Face%20Ever.jpg);`

Comment: "The Cutest Face Ever.jpg" I must see this picture.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid css lies here:

```
background-image: url: "../images/pictures of liana/" The Cutest Face Ever.jpg);
```

Should be:

```
background-image:url("../images/pictures%of%liana/The%Cutest%Face%Ever.jpg")
```

---

I suggest you to rename your folder and images without spaces and use something like this:

```
background-image:url("../images/liana/lady1.jpg")
```